# Proving linear maps are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: linear algebra done right 3rd]

In the proof above, when it says $a_1$$\varphi_1$ + ... + $a_n$$\varphi_n$ = 0, does it imply that the equation has to be true for all v $\in$ $\boldsymbol V$?

Comment: More or less yes, but the definition of the dual basis takes care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dual space, the  elements are functions on $V$ (of certain  kind).
So a linear combination of them being zero should be interpreted as being the zero function. So your guess that it is zero for all $v\in V$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because in the right side of the equation the $0$ is the null operator $0$, so the equations holds $\forall v \in V$.